# Python WAV audio play *Without External Libraries*

Tags: python, wav

I have been having some issues for the past few days to get this to work. All I need is to learn it once to get it later. So what I need is a good example of working source code to play a simple wav file. I do not want to use an external library only to get this to work. I honestly don't see the point in getting a huge library to substitute for one problem :/. So if I can get a (Once again, NON-EXTERNAL) example, that would be great. (I'm using windows, so winsound should work, but I can't get the winsound.PlaySound('Example'.wav, SND_FILENAME) thing to work.) Thanks!

Comment: `winsound.PlaySound` works for me. Please post of an example of a script where it doesn't work for you and what errors you get when you try to run it.

Comment: I will do that for sure, but could you also send me a bit in which it works for you?

Comment: `import winsound; winsound.PlaySound("test1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)`

Comment: Yeah, I did the exact same thing, but all I get is "<terminated>" after hearing the windows "outside error select" sound.